# Use a variable for key parameter in sorted function

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to have a different sorting key for each item of an array.

I'm trying to use:

```
sorted(response, key = lambda i: sorting, reverse=True)
```

where "sorting" is a variable that change on each execution of the for. Example:

```
sorting = "i['Name']"
```

My code get executed without errors, but the sorting is not as expected.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't make any heads or tails out of this problem. Could you post some input data and expected output, and some context?

Comment: `sorting = 'Name'; sorted(response, key = lambda i: getattr(i, sorting), reverse=True)`

Comment: What do you mean by '"sorting" is a variable that change on each execution of the for'? What "for"? Is this run in some loop?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(response, key=itemgetter("Name"), reverse=True)
```